# SQL query - comparing two items on distinct item

Tags: sql

Hi I'm a newby to SQL code and wondered if it was possible to get an output of:-

```
**EVT   John    Paul    Difference**
A1      1       2       -1
A2      2       3       -1
```

---

From the below data source.

```
**EVT   PERS    RANK**
A1      John    1
A1      Paul    2
A1      Ringo   3
A1      George  4
A2      Ringo   1
A2      John    2
A2      Paul    3
A2      George  4
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
      EVT,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='John' THEN Rank END) AS John,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='Paul' THEN Rank END) AS Paul,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='John' THEN Rank END) -  
                  MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='Paul' THEN Rank END) as Difference
FROM YourTable 
WHERE Pers IN ('John','Paul')
GROUP BY EVT
```

Comment: Is there any way to exclude records where one of the items is a NULL?