# SQL query - comparing two items on distinct item - REVISITED

Tags: sql

As an addon to the question I asked a few days ago here at [sql-query-comparing-two-items-on-distinct-item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904898/sql-query-comparing-two-items-on-distinct-item) would it be possible to remove the possibillty of null values where one of the 'pers' does not occur in the 'evt'.

**Output**

```
**EVT   John    Paul    Difference**
A1      1       2       -1
A2      2       3       -1
A3      2       NULL    [errors here] - ** item to be removed **
```

**Data**

```
**EVT   PERS    RANK**
A1      John    1
A1      Paul    2
A1      Ringo   3
A1      George  4
A2      Ringo   1
A2      John    2
A2      Paul    3
A2      George  4
A3      Ringo   1
A3      John    2
A3      George  4
```

**Current Code** (thanks to Martin Smith)

```
SELECT 
      EVT,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='John' THEN Rank END) AS John,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='Paul' THEN Rank END) AS Paul,
      MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='John' THEN Rank END) - MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='Paul' THEN Rank END) as Difference
FROM YourTable 
WHERE Pers IN ('John','Paul')
GROUP BY EVT
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a having clause:

```
GROUP BY EVT
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='John' THEN Rank END) IS NOT NULL
       AND MAX(CASE WHEN Pers='Paul' THEN Rank END) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
WITH NullSNotYetExcluded AS (

  --insert your SELECT statement from Martin here--

)
  SELECT * FROM NullsNotYetExcluded 
  WHERE Difference IS NOT NULL;
```

Another option (probably more costly to run) is to add

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Pers) = 2
```